# Outlook custom MailTip on MailItem

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Is it possible to modify an Outlook MailItem object to display a Mailtip with custom text? It doesn't look to be possible using the OOM, how about at the MAPI layer, i.e. using Redemption?

If not possible, is there some way to achieve a similar effect? (e.g. Ribbon XML, etc.)

[mailtip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znJBt.png)

[image: mailtip example 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is add a category - it will be displayed in the same area.
The tip itself comes from Exchange server as a result of an EWS call. There is no way to display custom data there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still interested in possibilities to display MailTips based on your own rules with your own texts: There is an Outlook add-in called MailScout allowing that (mailscout-app.com). Kind regards

Comment: There is an API for that when running from a JS (web) addin. You cannot do that from a COM addin that is using Outlook Object Model.